# Mariadb connection fails through tunnel when bind address = localhost

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.1, ssh

I have a MariaDB 10.1.26 virtual server running on Debian 9. It is connected to via `ssh tunnel` and the `bind address = localhost`. It has been working without fail untill recently.
Now when I connect via ssh tunnel I get the error

`ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'.  system error: 0 "Internal error/check (Not system error)"`

Connecting locally is ok. Changing the bind address to `0.0.0.0` allows the ssh connections to work. The exact moment the ssh connections failed the only thing I was doing was trying to connect to the server with PHP with mysqli but can't see this being the cause. I have firewalled the port used but would like to change the bind address back. What would cause this change?

Thanks

EDIT: added full error message.
EDIT: I ran `strace -e trace=network mysql -u <user> -p -h 127.0.0.1` the line where the error occurs is:
`recvfrom(3, "", 16384, 0, NULL, NULL)   = 0` this `recvfrom` on a working connection reads `recvfrom(3, "b\0\0\0\n5.5.5-10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb"..., 16384, 0, NULL, NULL) = 102`

EDIT: I changed `bind-address = localhost` to `bind-address =127.0.0.1` and it works fine now? My /etc/hosts file hasnt changed.

Comment: I would like to suggest the `strace`, `lsof` and `tcpdump` commands to analyze.

Comment: please post the mysql and tunnel command line how you connect. Did you try with the parameter `--protocol=tcp`?

Comment: Fyodor, same when run with `--protocol=tcp`. the tunnel is managed by autossh and the command is `autossh -M 0 -N -q -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -p <port> -l autossh 192.168.X.X -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 -i /home/autossh/.ssh/id_rsa` and the mysql command when i manually connect is `mysql -u <user> -p -h 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @peterh `lsof -Pn | grep 3306` shows that the mysql server is only listening on ipv6 and not ipv4. Trying `mysql -u <user> -p -h ::1 --protocol=tcp` & `mysql -u <user> -p -h ::1` both return the same error. Changing to `bind-address=0.0.0.0` on the server allows connection with both ipv6 and ipv4. i havent got `strace` or `tcpdump` installed on the server. i will see if i can install it and learn how they work.